# authenticate jwt from multiple auth server using sping boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I need a resource server to be ablve to validate jwt token from 2 different auth servers. One of them has a issuer uri, and second only has a secret key (that's in resource server's config) and it uses HS256 to decode.

In this [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/multitenancy.html), multi-tenancy seems to be what i need. It talks about using `JwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolve`, but this does not work for me, as it will need both auth servers' issuer uri.

Any suggestions? should i create 2 different `oauth2ResourceServers` in this case?

Comment: *but this does not work for me, as it will need both auth servers' issuer uri.* Why should it not work? You could return two different `ProviderManager`s.